# Objective C - Scientific Notation "String" into Double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, double, nslog

I am reading in a text file with tons of values in this format: 1.36E-08

Is there a way to "parse" (i think thats the word i need) this value into a double?  If I assign it straight forward it gives me 0.

```
//this NSLogs out "0.00000"
double x = 1.36E-08;
```

Comment: Have you tried `NSString* string = "1.36e-08"; NSLog("%f",[string floatValue])`?

Comment: Do you mean turn a string of "1.36E-08" into a double?  Or display a double in scientific notation?

Comment: EDIT: Daniel had the right answer!! My issue was this: NSLog cuts you off @ 6 decimal places.  E-08 is too small.  If i try "E08" it works perfectly!! :D

*If you don't mind, submit it as an answer and ill flag it so others can see that it works as well

Comment: I'm confused now as Daniel's comment turns a string into a string.

Comment: The NSLog was just to confirm that it was operating as expected.  If you simply load each string into an NSString and do [string floatValue] it correctly print #.#### for #.0E#  (# = any number)

EDIT:  The following answer with NSDecimalNumber also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think You want this:

```
NSDecimalNumber *decNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.36e-08"];

NSLog(@"Number -> %g", [decNumber doubleValue]);
```

**Output:**

`Number -> 1.36e-08`

Comment: This also accomplished what I needed.  Thank you :)  

*Just tested it.  :D